# Is it always possible to find a constant K to prove big O or big Omega?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So I have to figure out if n^(1/2) is Big Omega of log(n)^3. I am pretty sure that it is not, since n^(1/2) is not even in the bounds of log(n)^3; but I do not know how to prove it without limits. I know the definition without limits is

> *g(n) is big Omega of f(n) iff there is a constant c > 0 and an
>   integer constant n0 => 1 such that f(n) => c*g(n) for n => n0

But can I really always find a constant c that will satisfy this?

for instance for log(n)^3=>c*n^(1/2) if c = 0.1 and n = 10 then we get 1=>0.316.

Comment: You don't pick an `n`, you pick `n0`, where it must hold for **every** `n` from that point onward ("for n => n0"). No matter which `c` you pick, it will stop being true for a big enough `n` (thus it doesn't matter which `n0` you pick).

Comment: Why you don't want to use limits?

Comment: As @Dukeling explained, you read the definition wrong. The formal definition demands to pick a constant `k` and a `n0`. The statement must then hold **for all** `n > n0`. See the [definition from Wikipedia](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/5c4fda723d05b428c85f37361ebb0cdf3c1c9e9d).

Comment: Leandro Caniglia tbh I wouldn't mind using limits in general but 1) my professor wants me to not use limits in the final answer and 2) I want to know for myself how am I reading this definition wrong.

Comment: @Zabuza thank you for the explanation. I think I understand it now. I need to find one k and n0 such that the statement will hold for EVERY n > n0. 

like that example I gave wont work since at n=100,000,000 the statement will be 512=>1,000. which is false. thuse disproving it.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing `sqrt(n)` with `ln(n)^3` what happens is that

```
ln(n)^3 <= sqrt(n)                         ; for all n >= N0
```

**How do I know?** *Because I printed out sufficient samples of both expressions as to convince myself which dominated the other.*

To see this more formally, let's first assume that we have already found `N0` (we will do that later) and let's prove by induction that if the inequality holds for `n >= N0`, it will also hold for `n+1`.

Note that I'm using `ln` in base `e` for the sake of simplicity.

Equivalently, we have to show that

```
ln(n + 1) <= (n + 1)^(1/6)
```

Now

```
ln(n + 1) = ln(n + 1) - ln(n) + ln(n)
          = ln(1 + 1/n) + ln(n)
         <= ln(1 + 1/n) + n^(1/6)          ; inductive hypethesis
```

From the definition of `e` we know

```
        e = limit (1 + 1/n)^n
```

taking logarithms

```
        1 = limit n*ln(1 + 1/n)
```

Therefore, there exits `N0` such that

```
        n*ln(1 + 1/n) <= 2                 ; for all n >= N0
```

so

```
        ln(1 + 1/n) <= 2/n
                    <= 1
```

Using this above, we get

```
        ln(n + 1) <= 1 + n^(1/6)
                  <= (n+1)^(1/6)
```

as we wanted.

We are now left with the task of finding some `N0` such that

```
ln(N0) <= N0^(1/6)
```

let's take `N0 = e^(6k)` for some value of `k` that we will are about to find. We get

```
ln(N0) = 6k
N0^(1/6) = e^k
```

so, we only need to pick `k` such that `6k < e^k`, which is possible because the right hand side grows much faster than the left.